# "ist" oder "sind" bei Aufzählungen

Tags: verb, grammatical-number, grammaticality, list

Üblicherweise verwendet man bei Aufzählungen den Plural. In konkreten Fällen kann sich das aber schon einmal komisch anhören.
Beispiel:

> Folglich sind in Abbildung 1 ein Subsystem und in Abbildung 2 vier
>   Subsysteme dargestellt.

Alternativ könnte man (fälschlicherweise?) auch den Singular verwenden, was die Sache aber auch nicht wesentlich verbessert:

> Folglich ist in Abbildung 1 ein Subsystem und in Abbildung 2 vier
>   Subsysteme dargestellt.

Welche der dargestellten Varianten ist „richtig“ und was sind besser klingende Alternativen?

Comment: Ich weiß, was du meinst, aber in diesem Beispiel klingt Variante 1 für mich überhaupt nicht komisch.

Comment: @Stefan Walter: wenn du weißt, was ich meine fällt dir vielleicht ein besseres Beispiel ein :-)

Comment: Ein Beispiel, wo es mir schwerer fallen würde: "Folglich sind in Abbildung 1 ein Subsystem und in Abbildung 2 ein Supersystem dargestellt." Ich vermute, das ist falsch, aber mein Sprachgefühl hat kein Problem damit.

Comment: [Der Artikel auf canoo](http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Verb/Numerus-Person/ProblemNum.html) zu mehrteiligen Subjekten legt nahe, dass „sind“ richtig ist... leider kann ich keinen entsprechenden Dudeneintrag finden, [obwohl es zumindest mal einen gegeben haben muss](http://www.uni-protokolle.de/foren/viewt/259736,0.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ich glaube, der springende Punkt ist die Anzahl der Objekte, auf die sich das Verb bezieht. In deinem ersten Beispiel sind das fünf Stück:

> Folglich sind in Abbildung 1 ein Subsystem und in Abbildung 2 vier Subsysteme dargestellt.

Stefan Walters Beispiel

> Folglich sind in Abbildung 1 ein Subsystem und in Abbildung 2 ein Supersystem dargestellt.

(aus den Kommentaren) wäre nach dieser Regel ebenfalls korrekt, weil zwei Dinge dargestellt werden, auch wenn sie unterschiedlich sind. Aber der Singular könnte hier trotzdem besser klingen; vielleicht würde hier eine Umformulierung helfen, zum Beispiel mit Umdrehung:

> Folglich stellt Abbildung 1 ein Subsystem und Abbildung 2 ein Supersystem dar.

Komplizierter wird's in diesem Beispiel:

> Folglich ist in Abbildung 1 und Abbildung 2 *je* ein Subsystem dargestellt.

Hier würde ich automatisch Singular verwenden, weil nur ein Objekt erwähnt wird, auch wenn es in diesem Fall ein Objekt *pro* Abbildung ist.

---

Ich würde generell übrigens eher sagen, dass Dinge dargestellt *werden* und nicht *sind*, oder natürlich umgekehrt (siehe auch weiter oben zu Stefan Walters Beispiel):

> Folglich werden in Abbildung 1 ein Subsystem und in Abbildung 2 vier Subsysteme dargestellt.
>
> Abbildung 1 stellt ein Subsystem dar, Abbildung 2 vier.

Comment: Jetzt fehlt noch die Betrachtung von Profil und Porträt - in beiden Fällen ist Amy Winehouse dargestellt. (Gegenwart: `ist`, wieso könnte `wird` besser sein, wenn es nicht auf die Zukunft sich bezieht?)

Comment: imo your reasoning concerning stefans comment is not stringent, i added to my answer why think this. Would you say my reasoning is plain wrong/also possible as a german native? You seem to be more reasoning from a grammar view.

Comment: @user unknown: Dann schreibe doch eine Antwort über Profil und Porträt, oder beziehe dich auf meine Beispiele, anstatt irgendwelche einzuwerfen, die nicht dazu passen. Dieses von dir genannte Beispiel finde ich außerdem pietätlos. "wird dargestellt" bezieht sich nicht auf die Zukunft, denn es ist nicht Futur I, sondern Präsens Passiv.

Comment: @Hauser: I'm not sure if avoiding redundancy is the key to this. Redundancy is a very important part of natural languages. Of course you're right, people like to omit redundant parts when speaking; I'm just not sure that this is the reason. Though your reasoning sounds interesting.

Comment: @oregon agree, redundance is no language rule but maybe a important cause for conventions, at least it is this way in physics/mathematics afaik. But the linking of basically two very similar sentences in content points more to rendundancy imo. **But really would like to know if there is rule deciding wheter ist/sind is correct in stefans comment and on what these very basic rule is actually based on, if it exists and it is not only convention** If you can add this, you have my upvote ;)

Comment: Wieso pietätlos?

Answer (score 2):

It would be correct to write

> Folglich ist in Abbildung 1 ein Subsystem und in Abbildung 2 **sind** vier
>   Subsysteme dargestellt

its simply a convention to leave it out, as it doesnt change the sense.

> Folglich ist in Abbildung 1 ein Subsystem **dargestellt** und in Abbildung 2 **sind** vier
>   Subsysteme dargestellt

To leave out redundant terms/symbols like these is also quite common in mathematics. I wouldnt say this a special property of german language. You can translate both blockquoted sentences literally into English. Wouldnt call this a matter of grammar at all...

So your first version would be correct. Think mathematical, what do you want to express, where do you loose sense. From a set theory point of view, *ist* is wrong as you have several systems.

Of course too much use of redundant words always is boring and no good style, again thats why it is also very common in mathematics. You want to write something down as short as possible to be efficient and gather attention. But redundance is no mistake per se.

---

Concerning the comments and Oregons reasoning. I think Stefan Walters example is false as he stated. The important factor **besides** the number of objects is the **Syntax**, basically it are TWO clauses linked by *und*

> Folglich ist in Abbildung 1 ein Subsystem dargestellt. In Abbildung 2 ist (auch) ein
>   Supersystem dargestellt.

By inking these two sentences the convention is to leave out all redundant terms in the first clause and draw *sind* because of reasons of syntax to the front.

> Folglich (ist)sind in Abbildung 1 ein Subsystem (dargestellt) und in Abbildung
>   2 (sind) vier Subsysteme dargestellt

Thats imho the logic behind this convention. Maybe both are allowed, Oregon gave no official rule out, but as i stated above this convention seem to be more influenced by reducing redundance and regarding set theory. This explains to me **why the Singular actually not only seems to sound better**.

Comment: Your first sentence is wrong. *Dargestellt* cannot be linked to both *ist* and *sind*. As you have written it, it means *In Abbildung 1 ist ein Subsystem. In Abbildung 2 sind vier Subsysteme dargestellt.* But you're right about your second sentence being the correct "complete" version.

Comment: @stefan your example sounds right to me, but i dont think the first sentence would be plain wrong by rule. Otherwise you have to explain how the reader knows that it doesnt mean: **In Abbildung 1 sind ein Subsystem. In Abbildung 2 vier Subsysteme dargestellt** Thats of course plain wrong while **In Abbildung 1 IST ein Subsystem, in Abbildung 2 vier Subsysteme dargestellt** sound nearly best to me!? From this i would reason even more that it is the syntax, convention and the completion of the redundant words in mind by the reader favoriting SIND in the orig. question but IST in your comment!?

Comment: The reasoning in my last comment was wrong. user unknown has given in his answer a modification of your first sentence which is ok. The reason why your sentence is interpreted as I wrote is that you changed the position of subject and predicate.

Comment: "In Abbildung 1 ist ein Subsystem, in Abbildung 2 vier Subsysteme dargestellt" sounds indeed good, but only with the comma. These subtleties are really fascinating!

Answer (score 2):

> Folglich sind in Abbildung 1 ein Subsystem und in Abbildung 2 vier Subsysteme dargestellt.

In diesem Beispiel sind in Abbildung 2 4 Subsysteme dargestellt, was den Plural erfordert. Daher kann man es nicht mit dem Singular von vorne zusammenfassen.

Umgekehrt passt der Plural von hinten nicht auf das eine Subsystem vorne.

Entweder man bildet die Teilsätze in Teilen, die auch korrekt sind:

> Folglich ist in Abbildung 1 ein Subsystem und sind in Abbildung 2 vier Subsysteme dargestellt.

wie bei Hauser, oder man fasst zusammen:

> Folglich sind in den Abbildungen 1 und 2 ein Subsystem bzw. vier Subsysteme dargestellt.

Dann bezieht sich der Plural auf die vielen Abbildungen.

Comment: +1 für die Variante mit der Zusammenfassung.