# Plural or Singular

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number

> Für das Verfahren wird kein Antrag und keine Genehmigung benutzt.

Es handelt sich um zwei Dinge, die nicht benutzt werden. Sollte hier "wird" benutzt werden oder ist "werden" erforderlich? Das Folgende klingt irgendwie falsch.

> Für das Verfahren werden kein Antrag und keine Genehmigung benutzt.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ich tendiere wie [Hauser](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2274/plural-or-singular/2276#2276) und [Dragon8](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2274/plural-or-singular/2275#2275) zur 1. Variante im Singular, würde aber ein *auch* hinzufügen:

> Für das Verfahren wird kein Antrag und auch keine Genehmigung benutzt.

In dieser Variante wäre der Plural *werden* falsch. Völlig klar ist meiner Ansicht nach, dass in der folgenden Version ein Singular stehen muss:

> Für das Verfahren wird kein Antrag benutzt und auch keine Genehmigung.

Nebenbemerkung: *benutzt* klingt meines Erachtens nicht gut hier; besser ist vielleicht

> Für das Verfahren wird kein Antrag und auch keine Genehmigung benötigt.

Comment: `Für das ... Antrag benutzt. Auch eine Genehmigung wird nicht benutzt`. *auch* imho clearly underlines the two Sing. main clauses here additionally to *und*. I dont see how a Plur. can be correct here besides wrong convention?

Comment: Yes, _auch_ underlines the singular, but otherwise I'm not sure what you're saying. No, the Plural can't be correct here, and that's what I was trying to say in my answer.

Comment: @hendrik was no critics, but affirmation to use Plur. contrary to tohus upvoted answer whose reasoning i dont quite understand.

Comment: @Hendrik: Sorry, wenn ich das so deutlich sagen muss - aber das halte ich für falsch. Es bleibt ein mehrteiliges Subjekt, auch wenn ein "auch" eingeschoben wird. Damit bleiben auch die grammatikalischen Regeln anwendbar, die für solche Konstruktionen gelten. Daher -1.

Comment: @Takkat *weder...noch* may be nice, but has totally different function than *und*. It matches more `weder das eine noch andere Element aus dieser Menge` where a Plur. can make imo more sense...

Comment: @tohu: Versuch' mal Google, ["es wird kein * und auch kein"](http://www.google.de/#q="es+wird+kein+*+und+auch+kein") versus ["es werden kein * und auch kein"](http://www.google.de/#q="es+werden+kein+*+und+auch+kein"). Ist vielleicht nicht völlig überzeugend, aber ich bin mir recht sicher, dass der Plural hier nicht geht.

Comment: @Hendrik: Überzeugt mich tatsächlich nicht wirklich, nochmals sorry. Es geht hier einfach um eine grammatikalische Regel, die Anwendung findet, egal ob die Verneinungen mit "weder - noch" oder mit "kein - und [auch] kein" gebildet werden. Wir reden hier über unterschiedliche Ebenen. Plural vs. Singular kann man aus den grammatikalischen Regeln ableiten, "kein - und kein" vs. "weder - noch" ist Stilfrage. Die grammatische Regel gilt in **beiden** Fällen. Wenn man für eine dieser beiden Varianten mehr/nur Singular findet, stellt das die grammatische Regel nicht in Frage.

Comment: @tohu: Sorry, ich verlasse mich hier mehr auf mein Sprachgefühl `:-)` Die Grammatik ist schließlich aus der gesprochenen (und geschriebenen) Sprache abgeleitet und nicht umgekehrt. Siehe auch meine letzte Änderung der Antwort.

Comment: @Hendrik: kein Problem. Aber wenn jemand eine Auskunft haben möchte, ob eine bestimmte grammatikalische Variante **falsch** ist, die nach den grammatischen Regeln zulässig ist: dann ist es **falsch**, eine zulässige Variante als **falsch** zu bezeichnen oder die andere als "muss" bzw einzig mögliche. Sprachgefühl ist Geschmackssache, aber Grammatik ist Regelsache. Deswegen: zwei unterschiedliche Ebenen. Wenn Du schreibst: es geht beides, aber besser ist Singular: kein Problem. Da habe ich auch kein Problem, mich von der Mehrheit überstimmen zu lassen.

Comment: @tohu: Mich würde interessieren, was Du zu meiner umgestellten Version meinst. (Und: Wenn mein Sprachgefühl mir deutlich sagt, dass etwas falsch ist, dann bezeichne ich es auch als falsch `:-)` Ich muss zugeben, dass ich an dieser Stelle nicht firm genug in der Grammatik bin, um zu begründen, warum der Plural falsch ist.)

Comment: @Hendrik: Nunja, in der Sache (mehrteiliges Subjekt, beides verneint) ändert sich ja nichts. Und alle Deine Versionen sind ja auch gramamtikalisch korrekt. Ich habe mich ja nur daran gestört, dass Du den Plural ausgeschlossen hast. Was die Formulierung betrifft: "benötigen" finde ich prima, die Verneinungen würde ich doch lieber mit weder-noch formulieren.

Comment: @tohu: Meine Frage bezog sich nicht darauf, welche Version besser klingt, sondern darauf, ob Du in "Für das Verfahren wird kein Antrag benutzt und auch keine Genehmigung." einen Plural als zulässig betrachtest. (Und: Ausgeschlossen habe ich den Plural ja nur für die Variante "kein ... und _auch_ kein".)

Comment: Hmm - ja, m.E. auch hier. Aber um das zu belegen, reichen Online-Quellen wohl nicht aus.

Comment: @tohu: Puh, das hatte ich fast befürchtet. Für mich ist der Plural völlig ausgeschlossen, da "Für das Verfahren werden kein Antrag benutzt" sicher ungrammatisch ist, und der nächste Teil des Satzes mit "und" angeschlossen wird. Aber ist ist wieder bloß Gefühlsduselei.

Answer (score 3):

Die 1. Variante hört sich eindeutig besser an.

Beim Benutzen von "werden", sollten "Antrag" und "Genehmigung" auch im Plural sein, also

> Für das Verfahren werden keine Anträge und keine Genehmigungen benutzt.

Answer (score 2):

Generell: Der Numerus des Verbs kongruiert mit dem Numerus des Subjekts. Im Beispiel lautet das Subjekt des Satzes (etwas umformuliert, das Schema ist aber dasselbe):

> "weder ein Antrag noch eine Genehmigung"

Es handelt sich also um ein [mehrteiliges Subjekt, das mit "`weder ... noch ...`" verbunden ist](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Verb/Numerus-Person/ProblemNum.html#Anchor-Mit-14210). In diesen Fällen sind für das Verb beide Varianten korrekt, das Verb kann also ohne grammatikalischem Regelverstoß entweder im Singular oder im Plural stehen. Besser finde ich (subjektiv) die zweite Variante (Plural), da sie den Hörer darauf vorbereitet, dass nach "kein Antrag" noch mindestens ein weiterer Subjektteil folgt. Die erste Variante wäre, wie gesagt, ebenfalls korrekt, aber m.E. nicht so "hörerfreundlich".

Steht einer der beiden Subjektteile im Plural (siehe [hier](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1955/ist-oder-sind-bei-aufz%C3%A4hlungen)), gilt grundsätzlich dasselbe. **Ausnahme**: der pluralische Teil steht näher beim Verb. Beispiel, bei [canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Verb/Numerus-Person/ProblemNum.html#Anchor-Mit-14210) abgekupfert und leicht abgewandelt:

> "Weder Ihr Antrag noch Ihre *Bestechungsgelder* **veranlassen** uns, ein Verfahren einzuleiten".

Hier wäre der Singular "**veranlasst**" wegen des näheren Plurals "*Bestechungsgelder*" falsch.

**EDIT**: Noch ein Link:

- http://hypermedia.ids-mannheim.de/pls/public/sysgram.ansicht?v_typ=d&v_id=1625 (m.E. nicht so übersichtlich wie canoo, geht aber auch auf die "weder-noch"-Variante ein).

Comment: the old Q&A i linked doesnt really affirm your argumentation imho, but you cite it? It affirms the Sing. use. Also we have basically two Sing. main clauses here linked by *und*. I dont see how Plural can be correct here in any way from a logical/set theory pov. The canoo examples dont really convince me. They just give out whats seems common without source for the `weder...noch` case, which doesnt fit `und` from set theory pov. IMHO wrong analogy fallacy. For `Für das Verfahren sind weder ... noch ...` your answer may be more common, sry im so pedantic, but our answers are quite opposite.

Comment: imho the fallacy alot people make is thinking of `und` as `plus` and wrongly derive several elements - plural. Thats correct if one uses `und` for enumeration of things, but here it clearly links two main clauses imo, thats why canoo lists it probably as more common as the majority makes this fallacy and build this more common (but wrong) convention

Comment: @Hauser: yes, i'm citing it not because of the result, but because of the discussion around it. Regarding right/wrong: there may be reasons why a grammatical rule **may** be this or that way from a logical pov, but since we deal with a natural (not artificial), grown language, we will have to accept the grammatical rules as they grew over the time. If those rules allow both sg and pl, this is a matter of fact. Regarding `weder - noch` vs. `kein - und kein`: it's identical regarding semantics, and it's better style IMHO. That's why i wrote "umformuliert, das Schema ist aber dasselbe".

Comment: Then the question is, what is the grammatical rule here? I say, we have 2 main clauses linked by *und*. You say canoo is right because it is a official web source and has to be more correct than my reasoning and 2 others affirming Sing. So the majority here is wrong but your answer is right because of canoo? Is a rule saying both Sing./Plur. may be correct really a grammatical rule? Im very skeptical. I think you mix up convention and grammatical rule for the *weder...noch* expression, for single expressions there cannot be a abstract rule imho. A rule has to fit several cases

Comment: Sorry, Hauser: IMHO, it fits our case perfectly. There's no semantic difference between both versions, and it's the only rule for cases of "mehrteiliges Subjekt" that fits our case (not to mention it's the only rule with external, objective corroboration cited in our discussion...).

Comment: dont Sorry :) its just discussion as im interested in such fine nuances. I think our pro&contra are now clear. I still dont see your grammatical rule of "Mehrteiliges Subjekt" According to google number of results this is not really a very common grammatical rule if at all http://www.google.de/search?q=%22mehrteiliges%20Subjekt%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:de:official&client=firefox-a **Maybe you are right, but then imo you should clearly define what "Mehrteiliges Subjekt" exactly is.** Canoo seems the only pure source for this suspicious vague term.

Comment: Hmm - i think there's no doubt about "mehrteiliges Subjekt": in our sentence, there are two nouns and a single verb. The verb "references" both nouns on an equal level (you can change the order of the nouns without changing semantics). I would expect such a construction "mehrteilig". Regarding canoo: it's not the bible for me (trying to translate a german phrase), but IMHO it's the most concose, almost-complete presentation of german grammar that's available online. Linking that site has the advantage that you don't have to depict the complete grammatical structure.

Comment: @tohu: Bei "weder ... noch" denke ich auch, dass beide Varianten OK sind, aber es ist hier eben _nicht_ "weder ... noch" sondern "kein ... und kein". Das ist auch bei canoo abgehandelt, und [der Singular wird deutlich bevorzugt](http://canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Verb/Numerus-Person/ProblemNum.html#Anchor-Jeder). In meiner Antwort sage ich das ja auch (ich _tendiere_ zum Singular). Die Variante mit "auch kein" wird bei canoo leider nicht behandelt.

Comment: @Hendrik: hmm - da hast Du eindeutig recht. Zum Glück kann man downvotes rückgängig machen :)

Comment: @tohuwawohu: `:-)`

Answer (score 0):

["ist" oder "sind" bei Aufzählungen](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1955/ist-oder-sind-bei-aufzahlungen/1957#1957)

similar/same question. Same argumentation from my side. Singular is correct here, Plural only with either one of *Antrag/Genehmigung* Plural or both Plural.

Rule of thumb: Split it into two clauses - than you would use in both the Singular

Comment: Nein, das ist nach den Regeln der deutschen Grammatik falsch (Plural ist hier ebenso korrekt wie Singular), daher -1.

Comment: @tohu may be you are right, but if 3 answers dont affirm a Plur. use you should re-think/check your grammatical rule source. It doesnt look very reliable to me as stated above... *Mehrteiliges Subjekt* is a very artificial, mistakable, inexact and contradictory term imo